# When should I close response for Interceptor?

Tags: java, apache-flink, okhttp

I have a Flink Job that is making a POST Request and an Interceptor that's handling `429` error code.

Somehow I'm wondering if I need to close the response in the Interceptor.
Sometimes I'm facing a warning about closing the response, and I want to ensure that the code is working correctly.

Here's my Interceptor Class:

```java
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

    if (!response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 429) {
        LOG.error("Rate limit exceeded. Waiting 20 seconds.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Should it be enough if I close it before the return? Like the following

```java
response.body().close();
return response;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mustn’t close the response in an interceptor. If you do, the response will be unreadable to the code that made the request.